# Unable to access android camera in <iframe> tag in ionic3 project

Tags: iframe, ionic3

I am using `<iframe>` tag in ionic3 html page. `<iframe>` is referring to external java-script project which is kept inside `src/assets` directory which basically shows a page for video calling (Quickblox) for web application.

```
<iframe class="quickblox-view" src="assets/webrtc/index.html"></iframe>
```

But when I am trying for video call,I am not able to access android device camera. Also I can see error message on page as  `Error: devices (camera or microphone) are not found` which is error defined in quickblox project itself.

Environment Details :

- OS : ubuntu 16.04 lts
- Angular : 4
- cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
- Ionic Framework : 3.9.2
- Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2

Please help.